# How to add a new ObservableCollection on Button click?

Tags: c#, wpf, string, xaml, observablecollection

When I click a button from my form and enter a string into the `Textbox` that appears, I need it to create a new `ObservableCollection` list with that string name.

A label with the string name will then appear on the form. We then have created a `ContextMenu` for that label. From here you can add another string inside that list that you clicked on.

This is the save button for the string:

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string titleName = txtTitle.Text;

    _viewmodel.RenameTitle(titleName);
   _Addtitle.Execute(null);
    this.Close();
}
```

Then we go into the ViewModel class(*titleName is the first string entered*).

```
public ICommand AddTitleCommand { get; set; }

public ViewModel()
{   
    this.AddTitleCommand = new RelayCommand(new Action<object>((o) => OnAddTitle()));
}

private void OnAddTitle()
{
    NewTitle += titleName;
}
```

The `OnAddTitle()` method and the two below are where the problem arises. **At the moment, the `titleName` string is split up, and each character is displayed as a new collection (we are assuming) on the form, instead of a title being one collection. - There should be multiple titles with multiple collections, each title having its own collection. The title should be as one word instead of being split up into individual characters.**

```
public string NewTitle
{
    get { return newTitle; }
    set { newTitle = value; OnPropertyChanged(() => NewTitle); }
}

public void AddCollection()
{
    ObservableCollection<string> collection = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    collection.Add(NewTitle);
    Collections.Add(collection);
}
```

XAML code on the form binding an `ItemsSource` to the `NewTitle` property:

```
<StackPanel Name="Content" Margin="0,99,0,0">


        <TextBox x:Name="txtname" Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="200,0,500,0"/>


        <ListView x:Name="TitleList" ItemsSource="{Binding NewTitle}" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource Template}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}">
        </ListView>
</StackPanel>
```

EDIT:

This is what it looks like, it should appear as one string in a collection.

[image]

Comment: Why would there be a collection per title?  Surely you want a collection of titles?  You're binding to NewTitle, which is a string.  You want to bind to a collection.

Comment: @CharlesMager We want the collections different for each title, as each title will have a collection of question strings underneath it. Therefore, the titles will have their own collections, but as you validly commented, all the titles will probably be a collection too, but that can be left for a later date.

Comment: @Sheridan The last question was unspecific and the code was premature. Not to mention because of such a post, the answers were not relevant to the problem, which was obviously our mistake. Hope this clarifies the problem and answers your question.

Comment: None of this answers your question but you should read up on MVVM - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx. Get rid of the codebehind. Bind the TextBox Text property to a string property in your ViewModel. Bind the AddTitle Buttons Command property to the AddTitleCommand in your ViewModel.

Comment: what about to use a Dictionary?

Comment: @LeeO. Thanks for the comment, I'll have a read up. If you have anymore ideas, please post an answer.

Comment: @potehin143 Please could you be more specific, perhaps an answer if you could?

Comment: Ok but some letter. Now writing via phone

Comment: -1 @user3157821, your use of this website is troubling. You *repeatedly* ask the same questions and *repeatedly* ignore the answers. Do you know how frustrating it is for users who take time to help someone with detailed up voted answers, only to find out that their answers have been virtually ignored and almost identical questions have been asked again by the same user? I'll tell you... it's *really frustrating*! You've *repeatedly* wasted my and other user's time and it's not on. You've *repeatedly* been told not to save UI objects and to learn the basics, but still you refuse. It's madness!

Comment: @Sheridan Thanks for your useful comment. When for the past hour I have been reading Lee O link he sent me. From your earlier post you said you would "Leave me to my madness" yet you choose to come back and still comment? Please let me keep **Reading** this article and stop having a go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I highly recommend you continue researching MVVM because you'll want to change how you are using WPF. But I think your problem here is around the fact you are using an

```
ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<string>>
```

when what you really need is something like this:

```
 public class YourTitleClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
 {
    private string _title;
    public string Title
    {
       get { return _title; }
       set
       {
          if (_title.Equals(value))
             return;

          _title = value;
          RaisePropertyChanged(() => Title);
       }
    }

    private ICollection<string> _subtitles;
    public ICollection<string> Subtitles
    {
       get
       {
          if (_subtitles == null)
             _subtitles = new ObservableCollection<string>();
          return _subtitles;
       }
       set
       {
          if (value == _subtitles)
             return;

          _subtitles = value;
          RaisePropertyChanged(() => Subtitles);
       }
    }

    public YourTitleClass(string title)
    {
       _title = title;
    }       
}
```

Then your AddCollection method needs to add an instance of this class to the ViewModels collection

```
public void AddCollection()
{
   YourTitleClass newTitleClass = new YourTitleClass(NewTitle);
   Collections.Add(newTitleClass);
}
```

Make sure you change the type of Collections in your ViewModel to

```
ObservableCollection<YourTitleClass>
```

Now when you add a "subtitle" (or whatever this subcollection represents), you'll add it to YourTitleClass.Subtitles. And if you are using the parent level of the object it's YourTitleClass.Title.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the outcome is still the same and they still are coming out as separate characters. Any Ideas? I will add an edit of what it looks like.

Comment: It's because you are binding the ListView to a string. It is expecting a collection. In my example, you should bind the ListView to Collections.

Comment: Now that I have done that, it doesn't display the title, but rather displays `MVVModel.NewTitleClass`.

Comment: In your xaml, change the ListView to a ListBox. Then add DisplayMemberPath="Title".

Comment: Thanks! Yes this worked great! One last thing. Now that I changed the XAML, my ContextMenu which is joined to the generated label is not showing up when I right-click on the title. Do you know why?